# Window.Current.Bounds height without status bar, per orientation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm calculating the screen width and height, and it seems to be off. Looks like the status bar height or width is included in `Window.Current.Bounds`.

It's supposed to be 32px in height for portrait and 72px in landscape, but it seems to scale, since `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().OccludedRect.Height` shows 26.6667 and 60.

What's the best way to get my Screen height and width, which excludes the status bar?

```
private void LayoutControls()
{
    var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
    var scale = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().OccludedRect;

    if (bounds.Width < bounds.Height)
    {
        // Portrait
        bounds.Height -= 32d / scale;
    }
    else
    {
        // Landscape
        bounds.Width -= 72d / scale;
    }

    // do something with new bounds
}
```

It's never 32 and never 72. The `/ scale` works for some DPI phones but not 1080p. Investigating `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().OccludedRect` gives what seems to be the correct height, but does not update with the `Window.Current.SizeChanged` event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

try

`Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Height;`

as the documentation says:

```
Gets the visible region of the window (app view). The visible region is the region not occluded by chrome such as the status bar and app bar.
```